# How to fix weird issue where images disappears, user is getting log out and AJAX doesn't work?

Tags: 7, users

I have this weird [site](http://masao.carsu.edu.ph/myid/) occurrence running in Drupal 7.34 FreeBSD environment which is running smooth for about 3 years until the last two days. I login as an administrator. Below is the interface.

[image]

When I click the 'My account link', it redirected me to the page below:

[image]

The background color disappears and turns into white.

[image]

When accessing and searching something in my custom forms made through custom module by clicking the search button, it produces the error below:[image]

When logging in as a regular user, for example 'adalampayan'. If the user clicks the 'My Account' link, he can see the administrator panel with the administrator name above 'aegono' even if it is not the administrator.

[image]

[image]

In addition to that, when logged as administrator, I can see only one user in the 'People' section, when in fact I created another user 'adalampayan' which is reflected in my database. See two images below.

[image]

[image]

I did anything from clearing Drupal and browser cache, dropping the database and replacing it with newly installed Drupal tables. Replacing Drupal files to newly downloaded drupal 7.34 package. I created a local instance of this site in my work station and it is working fine. I dont know if this has to do with the network since it only occurs when uploaded in the server. If this has something to do with the .htaccess, sessions or what. Please do enlighten me since I really need to get this working. Any help would be very much appreciated. The server has undergone FreBSD upgrade after the site had the problem. I even restarted the server so many times.

**UPDATE**:
   I tried clearing the network cache and the background color was fixed. The list of users in people did also corresponds to the database. Remaining issue was even though the user was not the administrator , the admin panel with the administrator name still shows. The user still cant use or manipulate through to the forms, which is I think because it is confused who is login.

Comment: How is this an access denied issue if somebody is logged in? Does your company use any sort of caching mechanism on the intranet? It could be that you are served a cashed version of someone else's session?

Comment: @Neograph734 --> Please see my updated post.

Comment: Your Drupal version was released in November 2014, many security updates have followed (current version is 7.56), so it might be that someone is messing with your site, or it uses outdated (deprecated) php functions. Without server logs we can't tell. Nor can we make any assumptions on the network infrastructure. To me it appears to be a caching issue, maybe your IT department can enlighten you?

Comment: "*Debugging is the art of eliminating all possible causes for an issue*" ... Try to (temporary) increase the available memory (eg add 25% or 50% to it) and see if the problem remains. If it solves it, you've found the reason for your issue (= not enough memory anymore, eg because recently another module got enabled).

Comment: @Eliyah Can you clarify what's the problem you're trying to fix? Either AJAX error, 'background color disappears', 'access denied' page, or anything else? Is it AJAX error that you want to focus on?

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure that:

- Clean URLs are enabled in the admin panel (at `/admin/config/search/clean-urls`).
- Make sure `mod_rewrite` Apache module is loaded correctly by going to  *Administration » Reports » Status report » PHP section* and click *more information* (at `/admin/reports/status/php`).
- Verify `RewriteBase` value in your `.htaccess` file if you're using subdirectory.

The above suggestions are based on how your AJAX is requesting `"myid/?q=system/ajax"` (it should be `/system/ajax` or `/myid/system/ajax` if you're using subdirectory). Normally Drupal should support the version without clean URLs, however your custom code probably is not supporting this (so this is something to fix in your code, especially how you're generating links to the requests and images).

For the links for images, you should use [`base_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/base_path/7.x) followed by the path, e.g.:

```
$image_path = base_path() . "/sites/default/files/image.png";
```

This would explain why images and some of the requests aren't working properly, because Drupal accessing them via `?q=` parameter.

---

To troubleshoot this further, open *DevTools* (inspector) and check the Console tab for any request errors and validate the URLs based on the above. For AJAX error, check for *XHR requests* in Network tab and look for `/system/ajax` requests, then check the *Response*, most likely you'll see the actual error there.